# How to find the source of a memory leak in a Blockchain + Node.js game

Tags: memory-efficiency, debugging, node.js, memory

We have been working in a Node.js game, part of a game network, which seems to be working slower and slower as you keep it open, as well as it seems to increase the RAM and CPU usage over time.

We are assuming it's a memory leak issue/improper use of the data structures within the application.

The question is, how could I detect the source of this type of issue?

Comment: Hey Chris Russo, I changed the scope of the question because software/technology recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Use a profiler. I can't tell you which one because I don't know exactly what tech your using. But there will be a profiler for whatever environment you are in.

Comment: This looks to me like a general programming question that might get better answers on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) instead, or might have existing answers there to learn from without any wait at all.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback... The application is running on NodeJS, I'm banned from Stack Overflow, otherwise I'd be happy to post there.